# Having trouble with <wbr> and image scaling

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a page with text floated left and the image floated right. I accomplished that, but my webpage images and text need to be able to properly resize.  and width in css aren't working for me, unlike in my home page, so I was wondering if anyone could fix it.

```
<section>
    <div id="right">
        <img src="../img/placeholder.png" alt="Photo of --">
        <p>--</p>
    </div>
    <p id="left">Web and Graphic Designer beginner,<wbr>blah blah.</p>
</section>
```

and the css (I included all of it just in case, but the most relevant part is the bottom PAGE PORTFOLIO):

```
/*ABOUT CSS*/

/*GENERAL*/

body {

}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

    /*section*/
section {
    max-width: 940px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    color: gray;
}

    /*all styling*/
* {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

    /*all links*/
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: gray;
}

    /*visited links and hover links*/
a:visited   {
     color: #838383;
}

a:hover {
    font-size:105%;
}

/*HEADING*/

    /*header*/
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 0.5em;
    color: #8c8c8c;
    width: 100%;
}

    /*subhead*/
h2 {    
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #8c8c8c;
    width: 100%;
}

/*NAVIGATION*/

nav {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

    /*horizontal nav*/
nav li {
    display: inline;
}

nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2% 2%;
}

/*FOOTER*/

footer {
    font-size:0.75em;
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
}

    /*social media*/
footer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 15px 15px;
}

#twitter img {
    width: 46px;
    height: 37px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px 15px;
}

#facebook img {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px 15px;
}

/*PAGE PORTFOLIO*/

#right {
    float: right;
    width: 40%;
    height: 40%;
}

#left {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong [here](https://jsfiddle.net/23ofogao/1/)

Used your code except for:

```
p+img {
   width:50px;
   height:50px;
   text-wrap:true;
   float:left;
 }
```

which is  for extra text